# How to access the elisp code of an Emacs BUFFER object?

Tags: buffers

The Emacs documentation does not to cover easy observable aspects of the in a window displayed buffer and the short explanation what a buffer is:

> 28 Buffers
>
> > A buffer is a Lisp object containing text to be edited.

mentions only one aspect of this Lisp object.

But there must be much more to a buffer as described in

> 28.1 Buffer Basics

part of the documentation.

For example the *Customize ...* buffer displays a dialog window allowing various interactions like for example input of keywords to search for or choice of a color from a list of colors.

In other words the Emacs documentation does not mention that an elisp Emacs buffer object can contain beside the text, the text formatting information and pointers to embedded image objects ( information about this content can be obtained from the buffer using: `M-: (buffer-string)` ) also elisp GUI widgets.

So the question is:

**How can I get the elisp code able to re-create a Lisp buffer object in order to reproduce the visualization of the buffer and its interactive behavior?**

Comment: “buffer is more a dialog box allowing various interactions” --- It is because commands act on the buffer. See [28 Buffers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffers.html).

Comment: Please pose a *specific* question about buffers. You pointed to some of the doc. Is there something *specific* there that you find unclear? If so, ask about it. Is there something *specific* that you think belongs there but is missing? If so, ask about it. You might also search for uses of tag `[buffers]`. Just linking to the description of the moon at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon and then asking **"But what *is* the moon?"** makes little sense, at least not for a Q&A site.

Comment: *But what actually is a moon?* with pointers to aspects clearly not covered by Wikipedia would in my eyes make sense ... but ... nevermind ... I have rewritten my question making it hopefully more specific (but at the same time much less understandable for newbies).

Comment: I’m sorry, but there’s such thing as “source code of the Lisp buffer object”.

Comment: @Shynur : I have been through https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffers.html as you can see from the text of my question. Sorry, but I can't follow *it is because commands act on the buffer* . To my current status of knowledge the buffer is all of the following: the text, the formatting instructions and the commands. So there a no commands 'acting' on the buffer. The buffer content is executed by some buffer visualization function and result in the visible windows content including the interactive behavior by displaying elisp GUI widgets.

Comment: @db48x : instead of pointing out that I have no detailed knowledge about what I am asking about it would be sure more helpful to guess from the 'wrong' wording what it asks for and provide a better one I could update my question with. How is the Lisp buffer object created then, if there is no (source) code which creates it?

Comment: Give me a few minutes; I’m working on an answer.

Comment: This is an [X-Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  You *say* you want to "get the elisp code able to re-create a Lisp buffer object in order to reproduce the visualization of the buffer and its interactive behavior", but the truth is that you want to "write interactive interfaces like these already experienced while customizing or using help, create nice formatted text composed of multiple different fonts, write own extensions to code highlighting, etc", and the first thing has nothing to do with the second thing.

Comment: You are making lots of *assumptions* and then asking numerous large and vague questions predicated on your assumptions being valid.  I urge you to stop doing that.  Instead, pick **one very specific thing** you would like to know how to achieve, and ask a question about that one thing.  Start with the *very simplest thing* that you want to achieve, and describe that goal in detail.

Comment: @phils : thanks for nailing my confusion down to a point. Being on one side fascinated by appealing to me concepts and on the other side disappointed that the assumptions the fascination was based upon turn to be wrong I am balancing on the edge between keeping to be fascinated and giving up. Yes ... I should better stop assuming "if THIS goes so intuitively easy then ... THAT should be the same way too". Thanks again for your hints.

Comment: I think that picking **one very specific thing** at a time is not what will give me deep *understanding* of the way Emacs works. My experience is that deep understanding of the fundamental concepts enables me to achieve my goals by myself and even help others out of their confusion caused by lack of such understanding. It appears to me that it is hard to get here the right hints explaining in simple concepts how things work *because* of the bias towards *one specific thing*. Is it lack of own deep understanding making simple explanations of the underlying concepts so hard or not possible?

Comment: The common problem of experts in any area is to be unable to help newbies because they forgot how it is at the start and provide hard to understand explanations wondering from their perspective how it can be that the tutorials don't help assuming the newbie has not yet tried to read them and if then not with enough attention to detail.

Comment: @Claudio: "The common problem of experts ..."---Yes, exactly. But in fact, almost no one can clarify a concept or something else that requires some prior knowledge to a novice. This is like a primary school student asking a college math question. How to explain it to him? I'm a novice, just like you. My suggestion is to start with these 2 books -- <https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/> and <https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/tour/>. When you have problems when reading them, ask the community for help. Veterans like Drew, phils, NickD, db48x, etc., will be glad to help you

Comment: The problem is that this site is ill-suited for one-to-one interaction which is what you seem to be asking for: basically, ask a question, get some clarification (or not...) and, based on that, ask another question, on and on ad infinitum. This site is for "questions and answers - no chitchat" as the [Tour](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tour) puts it. Sites like reddit and places like the Emacs Help mailing list are better suited for that (e.g. they provide some history by using threaded discussions - here the only history is comments which are in any case discouraged - see "chitchat" above.

Comment: @Claudio I think you are trying to run before you can walk.  You are new to Emacs and hoping to rapidly achieve "deep understanding".  That is not going to happen.  Start simple.  Try to walk first.  Build your way up.  And if you're unsatisfied with that approach, then I have only one suggestion, which is to dedicate yourself to reading the manuals and the source code.  (A serious suggestion -- if you want to attain a "deep understanding" of Emacs in as short a span of time as *possible*, I believe that's your best option.)

Comment: FYI I think `C-h i g (widget)` is going to be of interest to you based on some of your comments; but there are *many* other concepts that you will be wanting to learn about, and you'll never magically acquire all this understanding at one time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Emacs buffer is nothing more or less than the following:

```cpp
struct buffer
{
  union vectorlike_header header;

  /* The name of this buffer.  */
  Lisp_Object name_;

  /* The name of the file visited in this buffer, or nil.  */
  Lisp_Object filename_;

  /* Directory for expanding relative file names.  */
  Lisp_Object directory_;

  /* True if this buffer has been backed up (if you write to the visited
     file and it hasn't been backed up, then a backup will be made).  */
  Lisp_Object backed_up_;

  /* Length of file when last read or saved.
     -1 means auto saving turned off because buffer shrank a lot.
     -2 means don't turn off auto saving if buffer shrinks.
       (That value is used with buffer-swap-text.)
     This is not in the  struct buffer_text
     because it's not used in indirect buffers at all.  */
  Lisp_Object save_length_;

  /* File name used for auto-saving this buffer.
     This is not in the  struct buffer_text
     because it's not used in indirect buffers at all.  */
  Lisp_Object auto_save_file_name_;

  /* Non-nil if buffer read-only.  */
  Lisp_Object read_only_;

  /* "The mark".  This is a marker which may
     point into this buffer or may point nowhere.  */
  Lisp_Object mark_;

  /* Alist of elements (SYMBOL . VALUE-IN-THIS-BUFFER) for all
     per-buffer variables of this buffer.  For locally unbound
     symbols, just the symbol appears as the element.  */
  Lisp_Object local_var_alist_;

  /* Symbol naming major mode (e.g., lisp-mode).  */
  Lisp_Object major_mode_;

  /* Symbol listing all currently enabled minor modes.  */
  Lisp_Object local_minor_modes_;

  /* Pretty name of major mode (e.g., "Lisp"). */
  Lisp_Object mode_name_;

  /* Mode line element that controls format of mode line.  */
  Lisp_Object mode_line_format_;

  /* Analogous to mode_line_format for the line displayed at the top
     of windows.  Nil means don't display that line.  */
  Lisp_Object header_line_format_;

  /* Analogous to mode_line_format for the line displayed at the top
     of windows.  Nil means don't display that line.  */
  Lisp_Object tab_line_format_;

  /* Keys that are bound local to this buffer.  */
  Lisp_Object keymap_;

  /* This buffer's local abbrev table.  */
  Lisp_Object abbrev_table_;

  /* This buffer's syntax table.  */
  Lisp_Object syntax_table_;

  /* This buffer's category table.  */
  Lisp_Object category_table_;

  /* Values of several buffer-local variables.  */
  /* tab-width is buffer-local so that redisplay can find it
     in buffers that are not current.  */
  Lisp_Object case_fold_search_;
  Lisp_Object tab_width_;
  Lisp_Object fill_column_;
  Lisp_Object left_margin_;

  /* Function to call when insert space past fill column.  */
  Lisp_Object auto_fill_function_;

  /* Case table for case-conversion in this buffer.
     This char-table maps each char into its lower-case version.  */
  Lisp_Object downcase_table_;

  /* Char-table mapping each char to its upper-case version.  */
  Lisp_Object upcase_table_;

  /* Char-table for conversion for case-folding search.  */
  Lisp_Object case_canon_table_;

  /* Char-table of equivalences for case-folding search.  */
  Lisp_Object case_eqv_table_;

  /* Non-nil means do not display continuation lines.  */
  Lisp_Object truncate_lines_;

  /* Non-nil means to use word wrapping when displaying continuation lines.  */
  Lisp_Object word_wrap_;

  /* Non-nil means display ctl chars with uparrow.  */
  Lisp_Object ctl_arrow_;

  /* Non-nil means reorder bidirectional text for display in the
     visual order.  */
  Lisp_Object bidi_display_reordering_;

  /* If non-nil, specifies which direction of text to force in all the
     paragraphs of the buffer.  Nil means determine paragraph
     direction dynamically for each paragraph.  */
  Lisp_Object bidi_paragraph_direction_;

  /* If non-nil, a regular expression for bidi paragraph separator.  */
  Lisp_Object bidi_paragraph_separate_re_;

  /* If non-nil, a regular expression for bidi paragraph start.  */
  Lisp_Object bidi_paragraph_start_re_;

  /* Non-nil means do selective display;
     see doc string in syms_of_buffer (buffer.c) for details.  */
  Lisp_Object selective_display_;

  /* Non-nil means show ... at end of line followed by invisible lines.  */
  Lisp_Object selective_display_ellipses_;

  /* t if "self-insertion" should overwrite; `binary' if it should also
     overwrite newlines and tabs - for editing executables and the like.  */
  Lisp_Object overwrite_mode_;

  /* Non-nil means abbrev mode is on.  Expand abbrevs automatically.  */
  Lisp_Object abbrev_mode_;

  /* Display table to use for text in this buffer.  */
  Lisp_Object display_table_;

  /* t means the mark and region are currently active.  */
  Lisp_Object mark_active_;

  /* Non-nil means the buffer contents are regarded as multi-byte
     form of characters, not a binary code.  */
  Lisp_Object enable_multibyte_characters_;

  /* Coding system to be used for encoding the buffer contents on
     saving.  */
  Lisp_Object buffer_file_coding_system_;

  /* List of symbols naming the file format used for visited file.  */
  Lisp_Object file_format_;

  /* List of symbols naming the file format used for auto-save file.  */
  Lisp_Object auto_save_file_format_;

  /* True if the newline position cache, width run cache and BIDI paragraph
     cache are enabled.  See search.c, indent.c and bidi.c for details.  */
  Lisp_Object cache_long_scans_;

  /* If the width run cache is enabled, this table contains the
     character widths width_run_cache (see above) assumes.  When we
     do a thorough redisplay, we compare this against the buffer's
     current display table to see whether the display table has
     affected the widths of any characters.  If it has, we
     invalidate the width run cache, and re-initialize width_table.  */
  Lisp_Object width_table_;

  /* In an indirect buffer, or a buffer that is the base of an
     indirect buffer, this holds a marker that records
     PT for this buffer when the buffer is not current.  */
  Lisp_Object pt_marker_;

  /* In an indirect buffer, or a buffer that is the base of an
     indirect buffer, this holds a marker that records
     BEGV for this buffer when the buffer is not current.  */
  Lisp_Object begv_marker_;

  /* In an indirect buffer, or a buffer that is the base of an
     indirect buffer, this holds a marker that records
     ZV for this buffer when the buffer is not current.  */
  Lisp_Object zv_marker_;

  /* This holds the point value before the last scroll operation.
     Explicitly setting point sets this to nil.  */
  Lisp_Object point_before_scroll_;

  /* Truename of the visited file, or nil.  */
  Lisp_Object file_truename_;

  /* Invisibility spec of this buffer.
     t => any non-nil `invisible' property means invisible.
     A list => `invisible' property means invisible
     if it is memq in that list.  */
  Lisp_Object invisibility_spec_;

  /* This is the last window that was selected with this buffer in it,
     or nil if that window no longer displays this buffer.  */
  Lisp_Object last_selected_window_;

  /* Incremented each time the buffer is displayed in a window.  */
  Lisp_Object display_count_;

  /* Widths of left and right marginal areas for windows displaying
     this buffer.  */
  Lisp_Object left_margin_cols_;
  Lisp_Object right_margin_cols_;

  /* Widths of left and right fringe areas for windows displaying
     this buffer.  */
  Lisp_Object left_fringe_width_;
  Lisp_Object right_fringe_width_;

  /* Non-nil means fringes are drawn outside display margins;
     othersize draw them between margin areas and text.  */
  Lisp_Object fringes_outside_margins_;

  /* Width, height and types of scroll bar areas for windows displaying
     this buffer.  */
  Lisp_Object scroll_bar_width_;
  Lisp_Object scroll_bar_height_;
  Lisp_Object vertical_scroll_bar_type_;
  Lisp_Object horizontal_scroll_bar_type_;

  /* Non-nil means indicate lines not displaying text (in a style
     like vi).  */
  Lisp_Object indicate_empty_lines_;

  /* Non-nil means indicate buffer boundaries and scrolling.  */
  Lisp_Object indicate_buffer_boundaries_;

  /* Logical to physical fringe bitmap mappings.  */
  Lisp_Object fringe_indicator_alist_;

  /* Logical to physical cursor bitmap mappings.  */
  Lisp_Object fringe_cursor_alist_;

  /* Time stamp updated each time this buffer is displayed in a window.  */
  Lisp_Object display_time_;

  /* If scrolling the display because point is below the bottom of a
     window showing this buffer, try to choose a window start so
     that point ends up this number of lines from the top of the
     window.  Nil means that scrolling method isn't used.  */
  Lisp_Object scroll_up_aggressively_;

  /* If scrolling the display because point is above the top of a
     window showing this buffer, try to choose a window start so
     that point ends up this number of lines from the bottom of the
     window.  Nil means that scrolling method isn't used.  */
  Lisp_Object scroll_down_aggressively_;

  /* Desired cursor type in this buffer.  See the doc string of
     per-buffer variable `cursor-type'.  */
  Lisp_Object cursor_type_;

  /* An integer > 0 means put that number of pixels below text lines
     in the display of this buffer.  */
  Lisp_Object extra_line_spacing_;

  /* Cursor type to display in non-selected windows.
     t means to use hollow box cursor.
     See `cursor-type' for other values.  */
  Lisp_Object cursor_in_non_selected_windows_;

  /* No more Lisp_Object beyond cursor_in_non_selected_windows_.
     Except undo_list, which is handled specially in Fgarbage_collect.  */

  /* This structure holds the coordinates of the buffer contents
     in ordinary buffers.  In indirect buffers, this is not used.  */
  struct buffer_text own_text;

  /* This points to the `struct buffer_text' that used for this buffer.
     In an ordinary buffer, this is the own_text field above.
     In an indirect buffer, this is the own_text field of another buffer.  */
  struct buffer_text *text;

  /* Char position of point in buffer.  */
  ptrdiff_t pt;

  /* Byte position of point in buffer.  */
  ptrdiff_t pt_byte;

  /* Char position of beginning of accessible range.  */
  ptrdiff_t begv;

  /* Byte position of beginning of accessible range.  */
  ptrdiff_t begv_byte;

  /* Char position of end of accessible range.  */
  ptrdiff_t zv;

  /* Byte position of end of accessible range.  */
  ptrdiff_t zv_byte;

  /* In an indirect buffer, this points to the base buffer.
     In an ordinary buffer, it is 0.  */
  struct buffer *base_buffer;

  /* In an indirect buffer, this is -1.  In an ordinary buffer,
     it's the number of indirect buffers that share our text;
     zero means that we're the only owner of this text.  */
  int indirections;

  /* Number of windows showing this buffer.  Always -1 for
     an indirect buffer since it counts as its base buffer.  */
  int window_count;

  /* A non-zero value in slot IDX means that per-buffer variable
     with index IDX has a local value in this buffer.  The index IDX
     for a buffer-local variable is stored in that variable's slot
     in buffer_local_flags as a Lisp integer.  If the index is -1,
     this means the variable is always local in all buffers.  */
  char local_flags[MAX_PER_BUFFER_VARS];

  /* Set to the modtime of the visited file when read or written.
     modtime.tv_nsec == NONEXISTENT_MODTIME_NSECS means
     visited file was nonexistent.  modtime.tv_nsec ==
     UNKNOWN_MODTIME_NSECS means visited file modtime unknown;
     in no case complain about any mismatch on next save attempt.  */
  struct timespec modtime;

  /* Size of the file when modtime was set.  This is used to detect the
     case where the file grew while we were reading it, so the modtime
     is still the same (since it's rounded up to seconds) but we're actually
     not up-to-date.  -1 means the size is unknown.  Only meaningful if
     modtime is actually set.  */
  off_t modtime_size;

  /* The value of text->modiff at the last auto-save.  */
  modiff_count auto_save_modified;

  /* The value of text->modiff at the last display error.
     Redisplay of this buffer is inhibited until it changes again.  */
  modiff_count display_error_modiff;

  /* The time at which we detected a failure to auto-save,
     Or 0 if we didn't have a failure.  */
  time_t auto_save_failure_time;

  /* Position in buffer at which display started
     the last time this buffer was displayed.  */
  ptrdiff_t last_window_start;

  /* If the long line scan cache is enabled (i.e. the buffer-local
     variable cache-long-line-scans is non-nil), newline_cache
     points to the newline cache, and width_run_cache points to the
     width run cache.

     The newline cache records which stretches of the buffer are
     known *not* to contain newlines, so that they can be skipped
     quickly when we search for newlines.

     The width run cache records which stretches of the buffer are
     known to contain characters whose widths are all the same.  If
     the width run cache maps a character to a value > 0, that value is
     the character's width; if it maps a character to zero, we don't
     know what its width is.  This allows compute_motion to process
     such regions very quickly, using algebra instead of inspecting
     each character.   See also width_table, below.

     The latter cache is used to speedup bidi_find_paragraph_start.  */
  struct region_cache *newline_cache;
  struct region_cache *width_run_cache;
  struct region_cache *bidi_paragraph_cache;

  /* Non-zero means disable redisplay optimizations when rebuilding the glyph
     matrices (but not when redrawing).  */
  bool_bf prevent_redisplay_optimizations_p : 1;

  /* Non-zero whenever the narrowing is changed in this buffer.  */
  bool_bf clip_changed : 1;

  /* Non-zero for internal or temporary buffers that don't need to
     run hooks kill-buffer-hook, kill-buffer-query-functions, and
     buffer-list-update-hook.  This is used in coding.c to avoid
     slowing down en/decoding when a lot of these hooks are
     defined, as well as by with-temp-buffer, for example.  */
  bool_bf inhibit_buffer_hooks : 1;

  /* List of overlays that end at or before the current center,
     in order of end-position.  */
  struct Lisp_Overlay *overlays_before;

  /* List of overlays that end after  the current center,
     in order of start-position.  */
  struct Lisp_Overlay *overlays_after;

  /* Position where the overlay lists are centered.  */
  ptrdiff_t overlay_center;

  /* Changes in the buffer are recorded here for undo, and t means
     don't record anything.  This information belongs to the base
     buffer of an indirect buffer.  But we can't store it in the
     struct buffer_text because local variables have to be right in
     the struct buffer. So we copy it around in set_buffer_internal.  */
  Lisp_Object undo_list_;
};
```

See [buffer.h](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/buffer.h?h=emacs-29#n305) in the Emacs source code. The text is there (the `text` and `own_text` members), the attributes are there (in the `intervals` member), the overlays are there (in the `overlays_before` and `overlays_after` members), and on and on and on.

> … in order to be able to reproduce the visualization of the buffer and its interactive behavior from this code?

As mentioned in your previous question, you cannot do this. You don’t *want* to do this. What do you really want to do?

Do you want to write a letter to your Grandma, and later view that letter as you wrote it? Then use `enriched-mode`; it gives you some nice wysiwyg text formatting capabilities, and the next time you load the file they’ll look exactly the same.

Do you want to write an email to your Grandma, and later view that email as you wrote it? Then use Gnus or rmail or mu4e. The next time you view that email in your sent folder it will look exactly the way you wrote it.

Do you want to record notes in a tree format, with TODO lists and source code blocks and tables too? Then use Org mode. The next time you open that org file it will look exactly the same as it did when you wrote it.

Comment: No Grandma to write a letter to ... and no idea how to 'use Org mode' ... M-x enhanced- gives no completions, so no idea how to change to and use `enhanced-text-mode`. What I really want is to UNDERSTAND what a buffer is and how it plays with what is seen in a window. With this understanding I can then write own interactive interfaces like these already experienced while customizing or using help, create nice formatted text composed of multiple different fonts, write own extensions to code highlighting, etc.

Comment: I can't see in the buffer data structure where it points to the elisp GUI widgets displayed in a window. WHERE do the GUI widgets come from if they are not part of the buffer data structure and which method is used to create the graphical output from the data stored as pointer to elisp values in the buffer?

Comment: I told you, those are overlays. There are overlays to turn a text region into a text box, overlays to turn a region into a button, or a hyperlink, etc. If you want to understand how a mode works, read the mode’s source code. For example, you could read `custom.el` to learn how Customize works. It starts with an empty buffer, then adds text, properties, overlays, keymaps, and so on to it to create the interactive widgets you see.

Comment: “What I really want is to UNDERSTAND what a buffer is and how it plays with what is seen in a window. With this understanding I can then write own interactive interfaces like these…” is the question you should be asking, btw. This whole business of finding the true representation of a buffer is nonsense, and you only asked it because you didn’t know how Emacs works. I suspect you know how webpages have a DOM that controls their content and appearance, and assumed that Emacs did something similar. Emacs predates the DOM; it was invented in the late 90s, while Emacs was begun in the early 80s.

Comment: Sorry, not `custom.el`, but `cus-edit.el`. Use `C-h f` to find the help about any function. If you type in `customize` and hit enter, it will take you to the help for the `customize` function. The help buffer includes a nice link to the source code you can click on.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes, I had programmed a longer time ago webpages using DOM and recently GUIs with Pythons Tkinter mainloop() and have now trouble applying this past experience to find in Emacs elisp code how GUI programming is done. In other words I have to ask a question about how Emacs elisp GUI programming works or find a minimal code example explaining it as I am overcharged with trying to see it from cus-edit.el .